# Swagger UI and Docker Container Communication

Tags: api, azure, docker, containers, swagger

I have a docker container running Swagger UI on port 80 and I have another API running in another container on port 32788

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/                  >>>  returns swagger UI
http://127.0.0.1:32788/swagger.json   >>>  returns swagger API def
```

But when I put the json file into the Swagger UI field and hit explore, it says

```
NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. http://127.0.0.1:32788/swagger.json
```

Any ideas on how to solve this.  The docs say that they should automatically be connected to the bridge network.

Below is the result of the network inspection

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "4b5cc1526055297df70dc9adc4959fcee93384c412fbf90500c041b5b83ed43a",
    "Created": "2018-01-17T03:48:39.2325461Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "257a15af9ab9b25c6c5622fb0ebe599e5703b2ca5f2e4eaa97a8745a21e7f9a9": {
            "Name": "pensive_neumann",
            "EndpointID": "22be4b781f75e071bcb0098b917b81b16ca493e9080848188dd7a811c27070ec",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "30de904a599a19075d5e20ef5d974a11be9d7e58a68d984a24f4af9e22c4d92b": {
            "Name": "naughty_mirzakhani",
            "EndpointID": "f704b3e103a82ca5c56d5955ac27845d8951cfe13f0bc3e1ccc8717ea9c28d39",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

Edit to explain how started each:

The API is part of Azure Machine Learning so its hard to say how it gets started exactly (unless there is some command I can run in docker):

```
az ml service create realtime
```

Swagger UI was started as follows:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Comment: Please explain how you are running both containers.

Comment: edited with answers

Comment: Have you tried to use the actual IP of the container (172.17.0.X) and not `127.0.0.1`? If you are **inside a container** and try to access `127.0.01:port`, this is the container itself, not the host.

Comment: Yes, the actual IP doesn't work either.  I think it is probably a port issue, have been trying to fiddle with that also to no avail.